# ELM 327 How i can know a calculated CO CO2 HC & NOx with ELM OBDII? Is it possible?

Tags: engine, emissions, scan-tool, elm-327, mathematics

I have a question, if i have many codes from my ELM 327 OBDII, Mass sensor, Km traveled, Lambda, Temp, fuel pressure, gallons x time, engine load....
hao i can calculated these emissions?

Answer (score 2):

***No, it is not possible to get true values from OBD-II ELM327.***

You have to have a dedicated exhaust gas analyzer to figure that out, like this one:

[image: Gas analyzer]

***But you can estimate it using a lambda sensor***

Although I fear that the theoretical graph is not going to be very useful in the real world:

[image: AFR Chart]

Comment: Thanks! I´ll try with these information, i know is not easy but maybe this formula exist,

Comment: If I'm interpreting that chart correctly, looks like you'll especially have issues calculating backwards for richer mixtures, where the O2 curve flattens out.

Comment: Hey! For diessel motor? Do you have it?